# Xamarin Forms. How to change an element while the application is running

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm asking for a seemingly fairly simple thing to change elements, but I can't seem to do it. My application has a simple Carousel View layout with a button on each page. When the button is clicked, the text on the button should change. I tried using the fairly simple method below:

```
void ChangeButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    button.Text = "some text";
}
```

It works as weird as possible. When you click on a button, the text changes, but it changes not on one button, but on several. Perhaps the layout itself is working correctly, but am I missing something? Anyway, I would like to know what are some working options?

I also tried to make the Carousel View source change when the button is clicked. Well, that didn't work either.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <CarouselView x:Name="PlayersCarouselView">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Button Text="{Binding Text}" Clicked="ChangeButton"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here's the c# code:

```
public ButtonList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PlayersCarouselView.Loop = false;

        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>() { 
            new Button { Text= "1"},
            new Button { Text = "2"},
            new Button { Text= "3"},
            new Button { Text = "4"},
            new Button { Text= "5"},
            new Button { Text = "6"},
            new Button { Text = "7"},
            new Button { Text= "8"},
            new Button { Text = "9."},
            new Button { Text= "10"},
            new Button { Text = "11"},
            new Button { Text= "12"},
            new Button { Text = "13"},
            new Button { Text= "14"},
            new Button { Text = "15"},
            new Button { Text = "16"},
            new Button { Text= "17"},
            new Button { Text = "18."}
        };

        PlayersCarouselView.ItemsSource = buttons;  
    }
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty shoddy, but I decided to use CarouselPage instead of CarouselView. I haven't done all the tests, but it seems to work. At least the button text changes as it should.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change button text when you click that button, you need to work on viewmodel like this.

Viewmodel :

```
private string buttonText;
public string ButtonText { get => buttonText; set { buttonText = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
public ICommand ChangeButtonText { get => changeButtonText; set => changeButtonText = value; }
public ViewModel()
{ 
  ChangeButtonText = new Command(changeText);
        ButtonText = "Old Text";
}
private void changeText(object obj)
    {
        ButtonText = "New Text";


    }
```

Xaml :

```
<Button Text="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding ChangeButtonText}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```